# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')

Tags: node.js

```
C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\İrem\7\üü> npm i (any package-name)

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ahmet\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-21T17_53_37_530Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: npm i (any-packagename)      always the same error

Answer (score 79):

If you're getting this error while installing react styled-components, and there are no mistakes in your filename, directory as mentioned in other answers, then you have 3 solutions.

The latest version of styled-components is v6 but there is some issue while doing `npm i styled-components`. So either

1. Use V5, `npm install styled-components@5.3.10`, OR
2. Use yarn, `yarn install styled-components`, OR
3. To use the beta version, `npm install styled-components@latest`

Comment: It looks like there's an [issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3998) tracking this.

Answer (score 19):

The following command worked for me:

```bash
npm install styled-components@latest
```

Answer (score 8):

It's because of the Turkish characters on your directory. Change these characters (İ,ü) and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when I had the same issue:

```
Use V5, npm install styled-components@5.3.10, O
```

Answer (score 1):

i found this in package.json and delete:

```
"webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
```

look package.json and delete some strange package names

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`yarn add styled-components`

I see other answers have got out of date.
I got this error while installing styled-components. Above command solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `npm i styled-components@latest`, while this adds styled-components to the app successfully, it added `16 high severity vulnerabilities` to the application, which might not be the best approach. I noticed this `6.0.0-rc` suffix added to the package version for styled-components, so perhaps this will be addressed in an update soon.

In the meantime, here is a version of styled-components v5 that should work well:

```
npm i styled-components@5.3.6
```

Answer (score 1):

1-Use **beta** version:

```
npm install styled-components@latest
```

OR

```
yarn add styled-components@latest
```

2-Use **v5**:

```
npm install styled-components@5.3.10
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the problem was related to Turkish characters. I can explain how I solved the problem through the following examples of file paths.

```
C:\{no problem here}\{no problem here}\{no problem here}\TASARIMPROJESİ\{no problem here}\reactJS>npm install
```

CHANGED TO

```
C:\{no problem here}\{no problem here}\{no problem here}\DesignProject\{no problem here}\reactJS>npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

In My Project it worked with

`npm install styled-components@latest --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**npm install styled-components@5.3.10** 
use an older version. It worked for me.

Comment: Consider specifying _why_ this works. is it a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

There's already an [issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3998) tracking this bug when installing styled components@v6 from npm.

But I found a workaround by installing using `@latest` tag.

```
npm i styled-components@latest
```