# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut') in React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

In React.js, if I install any package, then I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Deepak kumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-07T07_11_17_685Z-debug-0.log
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810819/npm-err-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-edgesout

Comment: Try chaning your foler from `Deepak kumar` to something like `deepakkumar`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error for react styled-components, then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76219567/19688856).