# i am trying to installed styled-component to my react application but it is not install

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

i am trying to install styled-component to my react project but it is not installed i am using npm install styled-components command after while it gives ellow mention error

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-24T00_25_21_503Z-debug-0.log

i already delete package.joson reinstall npm
my npm version is 9.6.7

Comment: Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810819/npm-err-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-edgesout